# How do I remove the “submitted by” text on Views in drupal 7

Tags: views

How Can I remove the "Submitted by" Text on Views in drupal 7. I know How to do this on pages, webforms. but how on views?

Comment: sorry my bad, I find the solution. administrator plz remove this question.

Comment: If you found the solution, just answer your own question (you are allowed to do that) and then accept the answer.  Future visitors to this site may have the same question and your answer could help them.

Answer (score 2):

Since the QA didn't care to explore on his found solution.

Assuming your view displays teaser texts / full posts, go to the content type settings (e.g. /admin/structure/types/manage/page for Basic page) and disable the option "Display author and date information." under Display settings.